# Use localtunnel and pass generated url to node command

Tags: node.js, bash, ngrok

Im looking to use `ngrok` on port 4000 and which is a command that will export a `Forwarding` URL. Every time this runs theres a new randomly generated URL.

I would like to pass that url `http://2e1v870f.ngrok.io` to a `node` `process.env` variable, rather then hard-coding it evey time.

For example in bash:

`ngrok http 4000 | <process/define_something> | FORWARDING={something} node index.js`

Plus these are in two running processes I've used `npm-run-all` to do something like this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                                            (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                online                                                                                                                                                 
Version                       2.2.8                                                                                                                                                  
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                                                     
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4041                                                                                                                                  
Forwarding                    http://2e1v870f.ngrok.io -> localhost:4000                                                                                                             
Forwarding                    https://2e1v870f.ngrok.io -> localhost:4000                                                                                                            

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                                            
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I've turned to using the [node wrapper](https://github.com/bubenshchykov/ngrok) for `ngrok` as I couldn't access the output from bash. Here's an example `start.js`:

```js
if (!process.env.ROOT_URL) {
  var ngrok = require('ngrok');
  var shell = require('shelljs');

  ngrok.connect(3000, function(err, url) {
    shell.exec('ROOT_URL=' + url + ' meteor --settings settings.json', function(code, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('Exit code:', code);
      console.log('Program output:', stdout);
      console.log('Program stderr:', stderr);
    });
  });
}
```